# Nvidia-SMI failed after Nvidia-drivers were update

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, gpu-driver

I wanted to update NVIDIA drivers on my Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed them by command `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510`, then I reboot my PC. And now when I use command `nvidia-smi` I get the error message:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Also, now I can't to change display resolution. How can I fix this issue?

Maybe I do something wrong. What is the proper way to install these drivers?

`dkms status`
`nvidia, 510.54, 5.14.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed`
`uname -r`
`5.13.0-39-generic`

Comment: please [edit] your question and add `dkms status` and also `uname -r`

Comment: I have added this commands output

Comment: ìs nvidia loaded?  `lsmod | grep nvidia` and `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` also `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem. There were not problems with drivers installation. It was nessecary to disable Secure Boot in BIOS.