# Installed Nvidia driver but nvidia-smi throws "

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, gpu-driver

In my new laptop with dual boot (Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.7 + Windows 11), I tried installing the most recent production-branch Nvidia driver (version 535) available for my GPU (GeForce 4070). While no error seems to be thrown during installation, when I try `nvidia-smi` I get the infamous error:

> NIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the
> NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed
> and running.

To solve that, I have gone through dozens of previous questions/answers asked here in the past. I tried:

1. disabling Secure Boot as suggested in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401138/nvidia-smi-failed-after-nvidia-drivers-were-update).
2. purging + reinstalling as suggested in this prior [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1475621/1761690):

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'   
   sudo apt-get remove --purge '^libnvidia-.*'  
   sudo apt-get remove --purge '^cuda-.*'  
   sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535
   ```

(I also tried purging and then installing via Software & Updates, or purging and then installing via the terminal at Ubuntu recovery terminal as root).

3. issuing `prime-select nvidia` as suggested in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074692/1761690).
4. making sure I have Wayland disabled, as suggested in multiple places.

Nothing helped. What else could I try?

Comment: After installing the NVIDIA driver did you reboot the system so that the driver is activated?  Also, you didn't post if there was any errors during the install with the 6.7 Kernel as that is a mainline Kernel and may not be ready for normal use yet.  The HWE Kernel version for 22.04.3 LTS is 6.5.0-15-generic which I know that the nvidia-driver-535 installs just fine into.

Comment: @Terrance thanks for your comment. So: yes I rebooted every time I purged / installed. No errors at all with the kernel installation and it's working perfectly (I need it because it solves issues with SSD and power management with novel laptops).

Comment: Check the output of `dkms status`.  If the driver was able to install into the Kernel correctly then it should be listed.

Comment: Is/has the gcc-12 package been installed?  If not, install it and try the Nvidia driver selection again so the gcc-12 may be used to build the module. An ongoing issue here and in forums (and bugs).

Comment: @Terrance `dkms status` returns: `nvidia/535.154.05: added`

Comment: @ubfan1 thanks for your comment. So, gcc-12 is available in the system, yes.

Comment: Yep, it didn't install the driver into the Kernel.  From that 6.7 Kernel try running `sudo dkms build nvidia/535.154.05` and then run `sudo dkms install nvidia/535.154.05 --force`.  Then rerun the `dkms status`.

Comment: @Terrance hm, interesting. That throws an error saying that kernel readers cannot be found. To solve that I tried the usual `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` but then I get `E: Package 'linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic' has no installation candidate`.

Comment: Download the headers from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.7.2/ and install them, then try again.  If you haven't, install the `-image` and the `-modules` as well.

Comment: @Terrance fantastic - it worked. If you want to put the steps in an answer I would like to upvote and accept it.

Comment: Added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present Kernel version you have installed, it seems to be missing the headers for it.  Since you are using a mainline kernel version `6.7.2-060702`, you should download both the `headers` and `modules` from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.7.2/

*Note that mainline Kernels are still in development and can be prone to errors and missing components.  Any bugs and errors should be reported to [launchpad](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs) for tracking.*

To install them is just done by running `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

After they are installed I recommend a reboot.

Since the driver installation only added the driver to the Kernel but not installed it by checking `dkms status` it will still need to be built and installed.

```
$ dkms status
nvidia/535.154.05: added
```

You can build it and install it now because the headers are installed so all you should have to run is the following to get it to complete the installation from the current Kernel of `6.7`:

```
sudo dkms build nvidia/535.154.05
sudo dkms install nvidia/535.154.05 --force
```

Then reboot again so that the driver loads.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this solved the original issue and actually a couple more that happened to be related to the missing headers. I accepted the answer and upvoted (although my upvote does not register since I have less than 15 rep).

Comment: @YzSun Feel free to edit questions here to earn Rep.  That is actually how I started here.  :)  I also just gave you a +1.  :)

Comment: thanks for the +1 and for the advice - it makes sense I'll do it!