# Installing Kernel 6.7 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, 22.04

I'm trying to install Kernel 6.7.0 on Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm running into the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-headers-6.7.0-060700-generic : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But then I saw this [other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1502029/1738783) on Ask Ubuntu and it looks like it is possible. Is there a way to get around this libc6 dependency? I would ask the OP on the linked question but I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

Comment: It seems you have installed kernel 6.7 in a "hacky" way - you should use the official mainline kernels. However, be aware that these mainly exist for testing purposes, so any bugs you encounter should be reported via official channels (as bug reports are off-topic here).

Comment: @ArturMeinild I was trying to install my kernel similarly, but the issue was that the headers file wouldn’t install because it couldn't install a newer version of libc6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Zabbly kernels](https://github.com/zabbly/linux), which are built for Ubuntu 20/22 and Debian 11/12. I was able to install kernel 6.7.4-zabbly+ (6.7.4 is the latest mainline kernel) and as far as I know, everything works well (including NVidia drivers)!